# Instant messaging limit in firebase

Tags: android, firebase

When firebase sets a limit of simultaneous connection to 100 active listeners,does that mean instant messaging can only be done amongst 100 users?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be referring to the [limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits) of 100 concurrent listeners on the Firebase Realtime Database on the free/Spark plan. That is the only product/plan that this limit applies to.

If you need more than 100 concurrent listeners on the Realtime Database, upgrade to the paid/Blaze plan - which removes that limit and then allows you to have up to 200,000 concurrent connections per database instance.

Comment: Yeah I know about the various plans but I'm trying to clarify what the 100 concurrent limit really means. In WhatsApp you receive message notifications even when you're not online.Does the 100 concurrent users limit mean,in a chat app for example,that I won't be able to receive instant notifications,even when I'm not online,once that limit exceeds.

Comment: If you mean push notifications, like those delivery by Firebase Cloud Messaging, those are not affected by the limits of the Realtime Database. Cloud Messaging is free and unlimited.